# Contextmenu in Safari extension

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension

I've searched for contextmenu with icon and Additional 3 sub menu items and can't seem to find a way to do that process to my Safari extension.  Are either of these things possible in Safari extensions?

Answer (score 1):

You can add an icon in your context menu, see the image on the Turn Off the Lights blog post (of the Turn Off the Lights Safari extension:
https://www.turnoffthelights.com/blog/apple-safari-support-is-dead/

[image]

```
lampmenu = safari.extension.createMenu("lampmenu");
sharemenu = safari.extension.createMenu("sharemenu");
lampmenu.appendMenuItem("totl", "Turn Off the Lights");
lampmenu.appendSeparator();
lampmenu.appendMenuItem("welcomeguide", "Welcome Guide");
lampmenu.appendMenuItem("supportdev", "Support Development");
var itemrate = lampmenu.appendMenuItem("ratethis", "Rate this extension");
itemrate.image = safari.extension.baseURI + "images/browser_star@2x.png";
```

See source of the open source Turn Off the Lights Safari extension: https://github.com/turnoffthelights/

Answer (score 0):

As my Experience there is no way to put icon in context menu item and also it is not possible to put second level menu(sub menu) in context menu. In Extension Builder of Safari browser there is no option available to set icon.